# Int.TryParse passing only boolean value to database

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, int, tryparse

At first I was having an error while inserting data into database. The error was:

> "Input string was not in a correct format"

But then I used `Int.TryParse` to convert `string` into `int`, and it worked. But the problem now I am facing is that `Int.TryParse` only passing just 1 or 0 like boolean values to database.

For example: If I write 34 in a `textbox` and click OK to insert. `textbox` is only passing boolean values to database. i-e; 1 or 0.

Can anyone please help me? Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
else{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ProductServices (ProductCode, ProductStatus, ProductCategory, ProductName, ProductDescription, ProductUnitPrice, ProductCost, ProductPCost, ProductPeck, ProductStock, ProductSWarning, ProductWarehouse, ProductPNotes, ProductImage) VALUES (@ProductCode, @ProductStatus, @ProductCategory, @ProductName, @ProductDescription, @ProductUnitPrice, @ProductCost, @ProductPCost, @ProductPeck, @ProductStock, @ProductSWarning, @ProductWarehouse, @ProductPNotes, @ProductImage)", conn);

        //Save image from PictureBox into MemoryStream object.
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        pictureBoxProduct.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        //Read from MemoryStream into Byte array.
        Byte[] bytBLOBData = new Byte[ms.Length];
        ms.Position = 0;
        ms.Read(bytBLOBData, 0, Convert.ToInt32(ms.Length));

        SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[14];

        //Create parameter for insert statement.
        param[0] = new SqlParameter("@ProductCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255);
        param[1] = new SqlParameter("@ProductStatus", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10);
        param[2] = new SqlParameter("@ProductCategory", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
        param[3] = new SqlParameter("@ProductName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255);
        param[4] = new SqlParameter("@ProductDescription", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255);
        param[5] = new SqlParameter("@ProductUnitPrice", SqlDbType.BigInt);
        param[6] = new SqlParameter("@ProductCost", SqlDbType.BigInt);
        param[7] = new SqlParameter("@ProductPCost", SqlDbType.BigInt);
        param[8] = new SqlParameter("@ProductPeck", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
        param[9] = new SqlParameter("@ProductStock", SqlDbType.BigInt);
        param[10] = new SqlParameter("@ProductSWarning", SqlDbType.BigInt);
        param[11] = new SqlParameter("@ProductWarehouse", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255);
        param[12] = new SqlParameter("@ProductPNotes", SqlDbType.Text);

        param[13] = new SqlParameter("@ProductImage", SqlDbType.VarBinary, bytBLOBData.Length, ParameterDirection.Input, false,
        0, 0, null, DataRowVersion.Current, bytBLOBData);

        int unit; int cost; int pc; int stock; int war;
        param[0].Value = txtCode.Text;
        param[1].Value = ComboStatus.Text;
        param[2].Value = ComboCategory.Text;
        param[3].Value = txtName.Text;
        param[4].Value = txtDescription.Text;
        param[5].Value = Int32.TryParse(txtUnit.Text, out unit);
        param[6].Value = Int32.TryParse(txtCost.Text, out cost);
        param[7].Value = Int32.TryParse(txtPC.Text, out pc);
        param[8].Value = txtWeight.Text;
        param[9].Value = Int32.TryParse(txtStock.Text, out stock);
        param[10].Value = Int32.TryParse(txtWarhouse.Text, out war);
        param[11].Value = txtWarhouse.Text;
        param[12].Value = txtNotes.Text;

        for (int j = 0; j < param.Length; j++)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param[j]);
        }

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        bmsmf1.loadProductServicesTable();
        this.Hide();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: `Int32.TryParse` returns a boolean, so the result is to be expected.  If you want to save the parse result, check out that funky `out` param you are not using.  Then read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: You should read the doc about [TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I think he/she is confused about the usage of out parameter more than anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Fast answer: Your code is setup for the use of `int.Parse(string)` replacing it will make it work just fine.

`int.TryParse(string, out int)` is a function that is used to be sure that when the string is not rappresentable by an Int32 it doesn't return the default value (as int is not a nullable type). If the TryParse returns true, the string was successfully translated in int.

Example of TryParse:

```
int num;
if (int.TryParse("1", out num))
{
    Console.WriteLine(num);
}
```

Example of Parse:

```
int num = int.Parse("1");
```

Comment: I tried this but I am getting an exception of "Input string was not in a correct format" on int.Parse.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting a boolean is because you are passing a boolean. `int.TryParse(string s, out x)` is going to return True or False. If you want to access the parsed `int` value, you would need to use the `x` variable you assigned in the `out` portion.

Comment: Can you give me a demo code? It would help me a lot. Please.

Comment: @user8441838 you don't need demo code, you **need** to read the documentation

Comment: @user8441838 my answer is pretty much demo code. I agree with @maccettura, you would be better served by becoming familiar with what `TryParse` does.

Comment: I read the documentation and it worked but only for one value. Remaining TryParse still passing boolean values.

Comment: @user8441838 `TryParse` is always going to return a boolean. That is what it does. If it ever stops doing that let me know because I have a lot of code that is going to get buggy as hell. You need to be using the value that is assigned to your `out` parameter. `TryParse` allows you to attempt to parse a string to an integer. It will tell you if that was a success or failure. And then, to save you time, it is nice enough to go ahead and parse that string for you if it can. So if `TryParse` returned True, feel free to use the parsed value, now held in your `out` parameter.

Comment: @user8441838 just realized what I think you meant by "only for one value". `int.Parse` is not the same thing as `int.TryParse`. `Parse` by itself just trusts you and tries to make a string an `int`. If it can't it will throw an exception. `int.TryParse` is you saying "I don't know if this is really a number or not, please check for me, and if it is go ahead and parse it for me".

Comment: What is the best way to convert string into int then? I am getting same error "Input string was not in a correct format" on Convert.Int32 and int.Parse. And TryParse giving me boolean values. What should I do now?

Comment: @user8441838 `int.TryParse` is the best way to do this. It is going to return a boolean. Plenty of the provided answers (which you should really accept one of them at this point, they are all correct (except please don't blindly use Parse and just a try...catch)) show you what to do. In the case of `param[5].Value = Int32.TryParse(txtUnit.Text, out unit);`, if this is True, then the value of `unit` will be the parsed `int`. If False, then you need to figure out what value you would like to use based on what your system needs. `0` would be the most often used number for this case.

Comment: @user8441838 It looks like you need to learn the usage of an `out` parameter first. Please read up on that. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier) is a start.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are setting the Value of the field to the return result of the `int.TryParse()` method which returns a boolean.

Just set the value to the value return in the out.

i.e.

```
Int32.TryParse(txtUnit.Text, out unit);
param[5].Value = unit;
```

Comment: It worked but only for one value. Remaining TryParse still passing boolean values.

Answer (score 0):

Please See this example:

```
public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      String[] values = { null, "160519", "9432.0", "16,667",
                          "   -322   ", "+4302", "(100);", "01FA" };
      foreach (var value in values) {
         int number;

         bool result = Int32.TryParse(value, out number);
         if (result)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", value, number);         
         }
         else
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Attempted conversion of '{0}' failed.", 
                               value == null ? "<null>" : value);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Output**

```
//       Attempted conversion of '<null>' failed.
//       Converted '160519' to 160519.
//       Attempted conversion of '9432.0' failed.
//       Attempted conversion of '16,667' failed.
//       Converted '   -322   ' to -322.
//       Converted '+4302' to 4302.
//       Attempted conversion of '(100);' failed.
//       Attempted conversion of '01FA' failed.
```

If the conversion is done correctly, the `true` is returned else `false`. So `result` variable in this example is `true(1)` or `false(0)`.